# Flutter (iOS): app is not listed in Fabric dashboard

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, crashlytics

Seems that my problem is similar to other issues in relationship between iOS apps and Fabric dashboard.

I have iOS app build with Flutter. After installation of Crashlytics I do not have my app listed on Fabric dashboard.

I tried Product -> Clean, deleted Derived Data, restarted xCode - with no progress.
By the way, after proper installation and manipulations, mentioned above, Fabric plugin for Mac is also in expecting mode (I press "Build" but see only timer circle running around with no change).

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: I've been actually using it with Flutter on both iOS and Android without a problem. Did you add the crashlytics build script as well as the key in your info plist?

Comment: @miguelpruivo thanks for your comment! Yes, I have done this - to plist as well as AppDelegate.swift.